# Apply several functions to each element in a stream

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

I'm trying to take a stream elements, and apply a series of functions one element at a time. Each function one of several asynchronous operations (download, image transformations, uploads over a network, etc.). The libraries use different APIs (some Promises, some callbacks) so using Observables might simplify the API if I can figure out how to make this work.

Using `rxjs` I'm trying to work out the syntax to do this correctly, this is what I have attempted so far:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs');
const { download } = require('./lib/images');
const { transform } = require('./lib/operations');
const program = require('./lib/bin');
const util = require('./lib/util');

const files = util.fixFileExtensions(program.args);
const files$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getMetadata(files));
const download$ = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(download);
const transform$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(transform);

// Take the files, apply the download$ and transform$ to each element in the stream
files$
    .map(download$)
    .map(transform$)
    .subscribe();
```

However my syntax is off and I get an error. What's the syntax to make this work?

EDIT From the current comments and answers, here's the updated but it's still not passing the output of `download` to `transform`. Here's what I have:

```
function download({id, name}, callback) {
    const credentials = {....};
    const filePath = `/path/to/tmp/${name}`;
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    authenticate(credentials, err {
        if (err) throw err;
        files.download(...., (err, res) => {
            res.data
                .on('end', () => callback(filePath))
                .on('error', err => throw err)
                .on('data', /* write to file */)
                .pipe(stream)
        });
    });
}

function transform(filename, callback) {
     const transformations = /* load transformations */;
     const result = transformations.map(t => applyTransformation(filename, t));
     callback(result); 
}

const download$ = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(download);
const transform$ = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(transform);
files$
    .flatMap(file => file)
    .switchMap(download$)
    .map(transform$)
    .subscribe(console.log, console.error, () => console.log('map is done'));
```

This throws an error from my `download` function saying `TypeError: callback is not a function`, so `download` is called properly, but its output is not being passed to `transform`

Comment: What's your error? Do you need any result of the asynchronous operations applied?

Comment: Ah one detail I forgot to mention is that I need the output of `download$` to be fed to `transform$`. There's no error, but it doesn't look like the `transform` function was called

Comment: And do you need also the initial Input in every further transformation?

Comment: No, only `download$` needs the initial input, the rest of the functions massage their output to align with the parameters the next function needs

Answer (score 1):

Finally you need to take switchMap to apply asynchronous operations. Switchmap will subscribe to the inner Observable and resolve it:

```
files$
    .switchMap(download$)
    .switchMap(transform$)
    .subscribe();
```

If the value of download is needed in the subscription you must pass the inner Value:

```
files$
    .switchMap(download$)
    .switchMap(transform$, (outerValue, innerValue) => {outerValue, innerValue})
    .subscribe(valueOfDonwload => console.log(valueOfDonwload));
```

Comment: This runs but the `download$` function is receiving the entire array of `files` instead of one at a time, which breaks the function's API so there's no output

Comment: @charmeleon Then do .flatMap(files => files) before the first switchmap.

Comment: Thanks, the `.flatMap` fixed the issue of the first parameter being passed to `download`, but it's still not going all the way through; `transform` is not being called. I've updated the question with the current code and error

Comment: Can you give some Details of the Download function and the transform function?

Comment: So. The error says that callback is no function. It seems that bindCallback is not working properly with download.

Comment: Added a pair of dummy `download` and `transform` to the question

Comment: If transform also needs a callback function, then use 
const transform$ = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(transform); to call it.

Comment: Right, I have `transform` which is the regular function and `transform$` which is `Rx.Observable.bindCallback(transform)`

Comment: But for transofrm you are using fromPromise:
const transform$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(transform);

Comment: Sorry, I typed that up incorrectly because I have other things that I will need to add to the pipeline that emit promises, but in my code I do have it as `.bindCallback`

Comment: Then there must be also a switchMap

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for posterity, David's reply is on the right track, but still doesn't work. I managed to make it work after perusing this blog post which shows how to work with Observable sequences: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rxjs-and-node-8f4e0acebc7c

Here's what my final code looks like:

```
files$
    .flatMap(file => file)
    .switchMap(input => download$(input))
    .mergeMap(downloadedFile => transform$(downloadedFile))
    .subscribe(console.log, console.error, () => console.log('map is done'));
```

One thing I didn't expect is that my `.switchMap(input => download$(input))` doesn't seem to be equivalent to `.switchMap(download$)`; the latter syntax throws the error `TypeError: callback is not a function`

A second curious point is that `.flatMap` and `.mergeMap` are aliases - they have the same functionality which seems to boil down to "take the output of the previous Observable in the sequence". There's a nuance here that in my code, the first `flatMap` splits out the array from the previous Observable and the second one (`mergeMap`) takes the previous output and provides it as input to `transform$`. Since the syntax isn't any different I'm not sure how that works unless it does this stuff by default

Now on to tying upload functionality to this sucker and continue to fully automate my side gig.